# How to insert sessionStorage data using ajax request in Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-request

I'm very new to this ajax request using laravel and currently I'm stuck. I'm having trouble inserting the sessionStorage from database.

For example I have here in my sessionStorage:

```
  Key      Value
=================
gclid      12345
token      abcde
```

I want to get the value for `gclid` or `token` values using ajax and store it in the database.

Here in my ajax I'm having trouble how to get these parameter values and store it in my `db`. I have this condition to get the `key` of the parameters like this logic:

This is in my controller:

```
if(key == gclid)
   $traffic->traffic_type = $request->('gclid');
else if (key == token)
   $traffic->traffic_type = $request->('token');
```

How do I pass this variables in my jquery and add a request in my controller to fetch it using ajax?

```
var gclid = sessionStorage.getItem('gclid');
var token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
```

**Ajax**

```
// Tracking Parameters
            function storeVisitorParameters() {
                let url = '{{ route('trackvisit') }}';

                var gclid = sessionStorage.getItem('gclid');
                var token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
                
                const data = {};

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        data:data,
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                            if (token) {
                                return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                            }
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $.notify("Visitor Parameters Stored!", 'success');
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            console.log('server errors', thrownError);
                        }
                    });
            }
```

**TrafficController.php**

```
class TrafficController extends Controller
{
    // Store gclid or token parameters to traffic_tacking_table
    public function storeVisitorParameters(Request $request) 
    {
        $traffic = new TrafficTracking();
        $traffic->user_id = $user->user_id;

        if($traffic->traffic_type = $request->gclid;) // check if key = gclid
        {
            $traffic->traffic_type = $request->gclid;   // store the key in db
            $traffic->traffic_value = $request->get('gclid');
        }
        else if ($traffic->traffic_type = $request->token) // check if key = token
        {
            $traffic->traffic_type = $request->token;   // store the key in db
            $traffic->traffic_value = $request->get('token');
        }

        $traffic->ip_address = $request->ip();
        $traffic->domain = $request->getHttpHost();
        $traffic->save();

        return response()->json($traffic);
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/trackvisit', 'TrafficController@storeVisitorParameters')->name('trackvisit');
```

**migration**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('traffic_tracking', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('traffic_id');
            $table->string('ip_address');
            $table->string('traffic_type');
            $table->string('traffic_value');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my main goal is to only get the `sessionStorage` values and send a request to my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php controller, change this `if($traffic->traffic_type = $request->gclid;)` to `if($traffic->traffic_type == $request->gclid)` , you're comparing the values right ?? It should be double `==` and remove `;` inside if condition

In javascript catch csrf token as,

```
var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

In AJAX Request,

```
dataType: 'JSON', // Add datatype as JSON, optional still for good practice
 data:{
  _token: _token,
  gclid: gclid,
  token: token
},
```

Inside data {} you're passing the values (gclid, _token and your sessionStorage token) as JSON formatted data to laravel controller

Comment: So when I make a request through a controller for this one in ajax `gclid: gclid` it should 
be `$request->gclid` right?

Comment: yes exactly, left side is your key, and right side is value, together one pair...its JSON format